# Remove attribute of new created element in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, ckeditor

i want to remove the atrribute/class of new created element using enter key press event in ckeditor ,so how to remove it.
ckeditor version is 4.3
i have following code

```
     <p placeholder="start here.." class='test'></p>
```

Now i write something and press enter between text then it recreate the same tag with attributes.
i have idea to use editor.on() ot config.allowedcontent , but i m not get how exactly do that so i can remove this class or change attribute.

I dont want to use any plugin.

Comment: Please provide a minimalistic JSFiddle sample that reconstructs your issue.

Comment: open this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/235/
Then click on Source view of ckeditor. and write following
"<p class="demo">check here</p>".
Now again click on source so u will in view mode.
Now press enter between "check" and "here" , so it will create same tag like "<p class="demo"></p>" and i dont want the "class="demo"" again in new created element, i just want p tag.

Comment: I m using inline editing.

Comment: Check comments below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293946/ckeditor-inline-repeats-paragraph-ids. This question is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @Reinmar "After/beforeCommandExec" is not fired if i press enter,then wt to do

Comment: @Reinmar
hello can u plz give me solution to how to fire Shift+enter key press event manually
like..  editor.on('key', function (e) {
          if (e.data.keyCode == '13') {                     
             e.cancel();
             // editor.trigger(jQuery.Event('shiftKey')); code for fire this keypress event
          }});
Here trigger is not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
   CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev )
{
 var editor = ev.editor;
  
    editor.on('key', function(event) {
        var kc = event.data.keyCode,
          csa = ~(CKEDITOR.CTRL | CKEDITOR.SHIFT | CKEDITOR.ALT),
                classname;
        if ( kc==13 && (kc & csa)==13){ //enter
        setTimeout(function(){
             var element = editor.getSelection().getStartElement();
             if (element.hasAscendant( 'p' ))
                element = element.getAscendant('p');
             if (element.getName() == 'p') {
                if (element.hasAttribute("class")){
                        classname=element.getAttribute("class");
                        element.removeAttribute("class");
               }
             }
        },400);    
            
        }
    });
         
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f63qctjp/2/